# Cannot tap on annotation when animating

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mapkit

I've got my custom annotation. I animate it from time to time:

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
                        customAnnotation.coordinate = newCoordinate
```

and while this is happening I can't tap on it to call mapView:didSelectAnnotationView

I even added UIButton as a subview:

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 7.25, y: 17, width: 37, height: 15))
    let text = customAnnotation.displayedName
    button.setTitle(text, forState: .Normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.greenColor(), forState: .Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    customAnnotationView?.addSubview(button)
```

in mapView:viewForAnnotation but it doesn't work either. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below might be work for you.

```
 View.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear | .AllowUserInteraction , animations: {
                            customAnnotation.coordinate = newCoordinate
})
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the other `UIViewAnimationOptions` parameters you can pass to in `options` is .AllowUserInteraction

```
public static var AllowUserInteraction: UIViewAnimationOptions { get } // turn on user interaction while animating
```

To pass more than one parameter to `options` you pass them in an array, like so:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, options: [.CurveLinear, .AllowUserInteraction], animations: {
                    customAnnotation.coordinate = newCoordinate
```

Hope that helps you.